# Noise from bottom bracket

Tags: bottom-bracket, noise

I'm getting a strange cracking **noise out of my bottom bracket**. It started after I tried to pedal harder on a higher gear. What might be causing the sound? The bike is new and can it be the bearing?

Comment: How new is new ?  If its under warranty then don't mess with it, get the shop to sort it out.   Can you add a photo showing the area ?   BBs and transmissionss and pedals can make a lot of different noises.

Comment: i agree with @Criggie. a cracking noise doesnt sound like something normal, unless if its creaking you're talking about

Comment: i don't know what to actually call that sound. but its definitely not some kind that comes out of wearing out of any part.

Comment: What bike? The pedal, crank, and chainring interfaces are all potential sources of noise. Poorly manufactured pressfit BBS on higher end bikes often make cracking noises as well. Could you get a video of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cracking noise can be produced by nearly any component of your bike.

The frame transmits the noise and it only seems like to come from your bottom bracket (or you think it is the source because of pedalling).

I had a similar problem with several of my bikes - in my experience it is normally a component which is not 100% tightened.

I would check following things:

- are the quick releases tight enough (rims and seatpost)
- are the screws tight enough (especially on the saddle)

You can try to find the noise by stepping on one pedal while the bike is standing still.

Comment: Also check **both** wheels for loose spokes.  Harder pedaling puts more stress on both wheels, so if a spoke is loose it's a potential source of the sound.